# Update avisar alteração

Tags: java, oracle, sql-update

Tem como saber se um valor foi alterado numa tabela direto na aplicação?

Tipo eu dei um

```
UPDATE tabela SET valor = 1 WHERE id = 2;
```

E na aplicação aparecer a mensagem:

```
O Valor foi alterado para 1
```

O que eu gostaria de fazer é avisar ao cliente quando houver nova atualização do sistema na rede interna.

Eu faço isso, quando o Sistema reinicia, que ele atualiza automaticamente quando a versão é diferente da atual, mas gostaria de fazer isso em tempo real, tipo, no momento em que eu alterei a versão no banco aparecer nas máquinas que há nova versão disponível.

Pensei em criar uma *procedure*, mas não tenho ideia de por onde posso fazer isso.

Meu Sistema é em Java

Comment: Acredito que conexões assincronas sejam capazes de resolver seu problema. Aka: Ajax

Comment: Diretamente pelo banco de dados? Acho que tem que ser pela aplicação. O servidor mandar uma notificação para os clientes conectados, é possível fazer isso com WebSockets.

Comment: Você poderia fazer um modulo a parte que fica rodando em background e checando a versão, caso haja mudança ele envia alerta ao usuário.

Comment: esqueci de dizer que o sistema é em java

Comment: pois é, isso que eu quero fazer

Comment: Acho que seria tipo um listener do Firebase

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar uma [*Trigger After Update*](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/after_update.php).

Nela você consegue recuperar o valor antigo e o valor através das sintaxes `:OLD` e `:NEW`.

Com essa trigger você pode fazer o que bem entender: inserir dado em alguma outra tabela, atualizar algum dado, e etc.

---

[Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177723/how-to-call-java-class-from-oracle-trigger) tem uma referência de como fazer uma trigger executar um código Java.

Comment: eles falam para criar uma classe no próprio oracle e na aplicação?